# Connect to google cloud SQL postgres instance from node typeorm application

Tags: node.js, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, typeorm, google-cloud-sql

I'm getting this error when I try and connect `caught error @ main Error: connect ENOENT /cloudsql/<PROJECT ID>:us-central1:<DB NAME>/.s.PGSQL.5432`
This is what my typeorm config file looks like

```
  const config2 = {
    database: <DB NAME>,
    entities: Object.values(entities),
    host: '/cloudsql/<project id>:us-central1:<db name>',
    extra: {
      socketPath: '/cloudsql/<project id>:us-central1:<db name>',
    },
    password: ...,
    port: 5432,
    type: process.env.POSTGRES_CONNECTION as DatabaseType,
    username: ...,
    synchronize: false,
    dropSchema:
      process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' &&
      process.env.POSTGRES_DROP_SCHEMA === 'true',
    migrations: ['dist/migrations/*.js'],
    migrationsRun: true,
    cache: shouldCache(),
  } as PostgresConnectionOptions;
```

I also tried to connect via a connection URL in Postico 2 and I'm getting the error `Hostname not found.`

I have cloud SQL API enabled in my google project

Answer (score 0):

Did you add your network? If not, postgres will not allow to connect.

[image]

[image]

Try to use 'Connections'.

Comment: I just added my home network to test, and unless it takes longer to update than the card that appears in the bottom right of the gcp website takes to load, it didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To connect via Postico to your Google Cloud SQL instance, you'll need to tunnel over SSH on port `15432` using the downloadable [cloud_sql_proxy executable](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy).

The user you're signed-in as in your terminal needs IAM permissions of:

`Service Account Admin` (or `Service Account User` may suffice)

If you aren't sure which user to give this IAM permissions to, run:

`gcloud config get account`

Once those permissions are confined, a command similar to this would establish the tunnel (note the `&` at the end, which is purposeful!)

`./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=<CONNECTION_NAME>:<DB_NAME>=tcp:15432 &`

The `CONNECTION_NAME` can be found inside your cloud console under SQL >  'Connect to this instance' section.

Now with the tunnel open, you should be able to connect inside of Postico.

To ensure your app can connect, you may just need to assign `Cloud SQL Client` IAM permission to your app in the same way you assigned service account permissions to your local user.